# Delete unlisted google play app

Tags: google-play

What is the practical method to remove an obsolete app in Google Play so no user accidentally install it?

Years ago I unlisted a few Google Play apps because they were obsolete and are no longer working with the current version of our service.

Still screenshots of these apps appear in Google search results, especially in the image search results.

These results come from third party sites that most likely profit from ads by cloning content from google play store. Example of these sites are apkpure, mobogenie, downloadapk, apkzip, apkgk.

These sites link back to the unlisted app in Google Play making it appear legit.

Google is very clear that you can't delete an app.

**Is there a practical method to "delete" the app?**

I've considered replacing all images in the Google Play listing with text such as "DO NOT INSTALL".

Comment: have you tried this link Remove outdated content from google - https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/6349986?hl=en

Comment: @AmodGokhale the problem there is that a third party is mirroring the content. That's what users find in the web search results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you unpublish it, new users can't install it, even if they find it through search results.

Comment: If you're logged in as the author the app is still presented with full description and install options. There is no indication that it's not available to others unless you log out.